# Can't retrieve Int from Firebase

Tags: swift, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to retrieve Int from Firestore but I can't it says "Result of call to 'append' is unused"
Here is my code :

```
class pointsM: ObservableObject {
@Published var point = 0
init() {
    let db = Firestore.firestore()
    let user = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
    db.collection("Male").document(user!).getDocument { (snap, error) in
        if error != nil{
            print("Error")
        }else{
            let points = snap!.get("Coins") as? Int ?? 0
            self.$point.append(points)
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Change `self.$point.append(points)` to `self.point.append(points)`

Comment: It gives me an error. "Referencing instance method 'append' requires wrapper 'Published<Int>.Publisher'"

Comment: Sorry I just realized that self.point is not an array. Just do this `self.point = snap?.get("Coins") as? Int ?? 0`

Comment: The append function call threw me off

Comment: Why are you repeatedly force-unwrapping variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you are conflicting types, as well as dangerously force-unwrapping.

```
class PointsM: ObservableObject {
    @Published var point = 0

    init() {
        if let user = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid {
            Firestore.firestore().collection("Male").document(user).getDocument { (snap, error) in
                if let doc = snap,
                    let point = doc.get("Coins") as? Int {
                    self.point = point
                } else if let error = error {
                    print(error)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```